# Is this code [self configureView] in the setSighting: necessary which reappears later?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import "BirdsDetailViewController.h"
#import "BirdSighting.h"
@interface BirdsDetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation BirdsDetailViewController
-(void)setSighting:(BirdSighting *)sighting
{
    if (_sighting != sighting) {
        _sighting = sighting;
        //Update the view
        [self configureView];
// Is this code[self configureView] necessary which reappears in the later viewDidLoad? 
//After I deleted this line everything seems works well.
    }
}
- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
    BirdSighting *theSighting = self.sighting;
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    if (theSighting) {
    self.birdNameLable.text = theSighting.name;
    self.locationLable.text = theSighting.location;
    self.dateLable.text = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *) theSighting.date];
}

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//You see. It reappears here.
[self configureView]; 
}

@end
```

---

The code above is quoted from Apple's official sample([Your Second iOS App: Storyboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1) ).
Is this code [self configureView] in the setSighting: necessary which reappears later ?After I deleted this line everything seems works well.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The rest codes are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ommit `[self configureView];` in  `setSighting:`.

And One more thing why you are implementing `setSighting:` yourself, Cocoa provides you  `@property`/`@synthesize`, that is trusted and will be shorter for your code as you are doing nothing specific.

Comment: Thank you, Vaidya. The code is copied from Apple's official IOS sample. So I'm not sure if there will be something missed if the code line is omitted.

Comment: OIC. But I suggested to use @property, not writing your own setter/getter :)

Comment: Sorry, Vaidya. I find out I have gotten the voting right just now. Thanks,again.